# how to parse an xml file and print items in different order using php

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to parse an xml file and print the items in different order and also with some other text between. The xml file is something like this

```
<list>
    <item>
    <price>200</price>
    <title>Title1</title>
    <description>something here</description>   
    </item>

    <item>
    <price>350</price>
    <title>Title2</title>
    <description>something there</description>  
    </item>
</list>
```

and I want to have the output exactly like this, 2 different lines:

```
"Title1","something here","","200","1",""
"Title2","something there","","350","1",""
```

It's important to see quotes and commas.

I'm using this, but it is not enough. I don't know what to do next...

```
<?php
//Initialize the XML parser
$parser=xml_parser_create();

//Function to use at the start of an element
function start($parser,$element_name,$element_attrs)
  {
  switch($element_name)
    {
    case "PRICE":
    echo "&#34;";
    break;
    case "TITLE":
    echo "&#34;";
    break;
    case "DESCRIPTION":
    echo "&#34;";
    }
  }

//Function to use at the end of an element
function stop($parser,$element_name)
  {
  echo "&#34;,";
  }

//Function to use when finding character data
function char($parser,$data)
  {
  echo $data;
  }

//Specify element handler
xml_set_element_handler($parser,"start","stop");

//Specify data handler
xml_set_character_data_handler($parser,"char");

//Open XML file
$fp=fopen("shopmania_ro.xml","r");

//Read data
while ($data=fread($fp,4096))
  {
  xml_parse($parser,$data,feof($fp)) or
  die (sprintf("XML Error: %s at line %d",
  xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser)),
  xml_get_current_line_number($parser)));
  }

//Free the XML parser
xml_parser_free($parser);
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

I have another code

```
 <?php
$xfile = "file.xml";
$xparser=xml_parser_create();
xml_set_character_data_handler($xparser, "cdataHandler");

if(!($fp=fopen($xfile,"r")))
{
die ("File does not exist");
}

while($data=fread($fp, 4096))
{
if(!xml_parse($xparser,$data,feof($fp)))
{
die("XML parse error: xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($xparser))");
}
}

xml_parser_free($xml_parser);

function cdataHandler($xparser, $cdata)
{
echo "$cdata";
}
 ?>
```

and the output is

```
200 Title1 something here 350 Title2 something there
```

I don't know how to extract data and print it in the way that I want. Any help?
Sorry, I'm a newbie...

Comment: Checkout [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), writing an XML parser by hand is overkill for this job.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactely what the **[XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)** stylesheet language was made for. Transforming XML documents to different formats. PHP comes with the **[XSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php)** extension that's pretty easy to use. Examples are there, too.

**EDIT**
If that's an overkill for your purpose you should take a look at PHP's [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) extension that allows you to use a node like you would use an object.

**EDIT 2**

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<list>
    <item>
        <price>200</price>
        <title>Title1</title>
        <description>something here</description>   
    </item>
    ...
</list>
XML;

$xml  = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$list = $xml->list;

foreach ( $list->item as $item ) {
    // Not sure if this works, but if it doesn't, substitute the sprintf
    // with plain string concatenation
    echo sprintf(
        '"%s","%s","","%d","1",""',
        $item->title,
        $item->description,
        $item->price
    );
}
```

Comment: Any examples would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Here you go. I just outlined the basic idea - didn't test it, though.